# Is there a way to see what parts are not in a feature?

Tags: features

I am working on a site where I have content types with fields coming from several different feature modules. I've added organic groups with groups on most of those content types, and also added some content types and fields.

Now I need to package things up, update the features modules, and make new ones. I am going over things looking for overridden features, and adding fields that are missing. While I can see what is overridden, it can be easy to overlook new fields that I need to add, especially when I have to cross-reference different modules.

Is there a way I can see what featureable parts are *not* in a feature? Since I'm dealing with several different features, I can't just look at one 'recreate' page and see what I need to add. I would like to see a master list of what part is in what feature and what is still in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:

1. Using [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush), the following command will show you all the Features Components which aren't already claimed by a Feature:

   ```
   drush features-components % --not-exported
   ```
2. You can install the [Features Orphans](https://drupal.org/project/features_orphans) module, which provides a list of unclaimed Features Components using Drupal's web interface.